# Where to configure the wildcard when I have several modules each with its own routing module?

Tags: angular, routes, wildcard

I am doing a test project in Angular that has the following structure:

- Error (error.component.ts)
- Home (home.module.ts, home.component.ts y home-routing.module.ts)
- Hello (hello.module.ts, hello.component.ts y hello-routing.module.ts)

app-routing.module.ts has this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

home-routing.module.ts has this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

hello-routing.module.ts has this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent }
];
```

app.component.ts has this code to navigate to those components:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="linkActive">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/hello" routerLinkActive="linkActive">Say hello</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And finally, app.module.ts has this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { HelloModule } from './Hello/Hello.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    HelloModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So far everything is working correctly.
The problem is that I don't know where to put the wildcard for paths that doesn't exist. If I put in the app-routing.module.ts the following code:

```
{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
```

It doesn't matter which route I put. They all take me to the error page. But I only want to take me there when none of this modules are able to solve their respective routes.

How I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

The routes arrays from different routing modules will be concatenated in the order in which the related routing modules are imported. Thus it is important that AppRoutingModule is the last imported one if it contains a wildcard route.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    HelloModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your routing files:

---

in app.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent}, 
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
]
```

in home.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

in hello.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HelloComponent }
];
```

Comment: But I don't want to configure all routes in my app.routing.ts file. I want that each module configure it's own routes...

Answer (score 0):

When structuring your Angular application's routing, it's crucial to carefully arrange the order of your route imports and module configurations. This is especially important when you're working with wildcard routes (routes that catch all unmatched paths). To ensure proper functionality, it's recommended to import the module containing the wildcard routes as the final import. This ensures that the intended behavior is maintained.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).